# Alternative to "local_file" in terraform to read dynamic file

Tags: terraform

What are the alternatives to read a dynamically generated local file without using "local_file" block? The problem with the "local_file" is the result data exists only temporarily during a Terraform operation and it is re-calculated each time a new plan is created, and this does not suit our requirement.

Can I use "null_resource" or any other stuff which won't be re-calculated and after first apply stored in the terraform statefile.

Comment: I don't understand your use case, regardless of it being in the state file or it being read from the file system, you have to load the file content into memory anyways? What difference does it make? Or is it that the file contents would have changed next run and you want to use the older contents? Could you expand on your use case?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using aws, why don't you save the data to an dynamodb table?
If you always use the same key, the record will be updated every run, if you change the key, you can have all the records saved for later.

Just little reminder, when posting a question, if you paste the code with it, it makes it easier for people to understand what you are trying to do. The quality of answers will be higher.